# Displaying array values on page

Tags: javascript

```
var msg = new Array(); 

msg [0] = 'Credit Card number is invalid';
msg [1] = 'Card holders name is required';
```

id like the relevant message to come up when my form is submitted. Form example:

```
<form id="PaymentForm" name="PaymentForm" method="post" action="#" class="big_box background border_solid">

  <input type="text" name="CardNumber" id="CardNumber" size="25" maxlength="25" />
  <span id="CardNumberMessage" style="display:none;color:red"><xsl:text> </xsl:text>*</span>

  <div id="FieldsRequired"></div>

  <input name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" type="submit" />    

</form>
```

so when the first field, in this case CardNumber is incorrect an * is placed next to the field and a message comes up next to the submit in the FieldsRequired div is saying whats in the Array msg[0]. I have two functions that show or hide the spans.

```
 function showStuff(id,msg) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
document.getElementById(FieldsRequired).value;<!--this part might be wrong-->

 };

 function hideStuff(id,msg) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(FieldsRequired).value;
 };
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since FieldsRequired is a div, you should use innerHTML futhermore FieldsRequired is not a variable name but an div identifier : 
`document.getElementById('FieldsRequired').innerHTML='your message'`

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value

```
document.getElementById(FieldsRequired).value=msg[1];
```